# Remove extension from filename

Tags: file, batch-file, zip, 7zip

In `folder1` I have a list of files:

```
file1.exe
ahahdf.exe
ahdfkqkq.exe
```

I want to run a script and have it create the following files in folder2:

```
file1.zip
ahahdf.zip
ahdfkqkq.zip
```

My attempt:

```
for %%f in (*.*) do "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a %%f.zip %%f
```

This creates `file1.exe.zip`, ... but I need `file1.zip`, ... (without the `.exe` extension).

How can I do this?

Comment: You should clarify your text, I can't see any question nor a understandable description

Answer (score 1):

Should be

`for %%f in (*.*) do "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a %%~nf.zip %%f`

Note `%%~nf` - `~n` tells command interpreter to pick the filename part without extension.

Also I would enclose parameters into double-quotes ("param") to ensure that filenames that contain spaces are properly handled.