# Trying to write a Bat file to copy files based on names on a list

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a script to get all the file names in a folder without the extension. And then from that txt file with all names I want to copy each file with that name in a folder anywhere. So folder B would have all the files I need with .pdf on it and I want to get the .doc file from folder A with the corresponding name as B

Example
Folder B = 123.doc.pdf, 234.doc.pdf, 345.doc.pdf

Folder A = 123.doc, 234.doc, 345.doc, 1324.doc, 54353.doc, 1231.doc

I want to get the names from B without the .pdf and then use that txt file to copy the doc files from folder A in a new folder C.

I created a script to get all file names but not sure how to remove the extension and safe it to the file.

```
dir /a /b /-p /o:gen >FileNames.txt
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: On which operating system? Windows or Linux? Please **edit your question** to improve it. Show some [MCVE]. Notice that  `dir` is not a usual Linux command (you would prefer `ls`)

Comment: Bash and batch-file are opposites. Bash is for *nix systems, while batch files refer to the Windows console. Which are you actually using?

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `FOR /?`.  Read the last section about the modifiers you can use.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am trying to write the script on windows.

Comment: @KenWhite Writing it for windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13893460/62576

Comment: see `for /?` especially the modifiers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
md "C:\Temp\Folder C" 2>nul
for %%I in ("C:\Temp\Folder B\*.doc.pdf") do if exist "C:\Temp\Folder A\%%~nI" copy /Y "C:\Temp\Folder A\%%~nI" "C:\Temp\Folder C\" >nul
rd "C:\Temp\Folder C" 2>nul
```

The second command line creates `Folder C` with suppressing any error message like the one output on this folder is existing already written to handle **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

The third command line uses command **FOR** to search for any non hidden file in `Folder B` with file name matching the wildcard pattern `*.doc.pdf`.

For each found file in `Folder B` an **IF** condition is executed to check if a file with same name without file extension `.pdf` exists in `Folder A`. If that condition is true the file is copied to `Folder C` with overwriting an existing file in `Folder C` with same name, except having read-only attribute set, and with suppressing the success message written to handle **STDOUT** by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Last the `Folder C` is deleted, but only if being empty. The error message output to handle **STDERR** on `Folder C` containing a file is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rd /?`